# Reindex typescript file in VS code does not run automatically

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to reindex specific file in Visual Studio code in typescript??

I have watcher (using nodemon) and script which recreate whole API.ts file and vs code does not reindex it automatically (if there is change in typescript interface, autocomplete wont notice it).